# What are good ways to find the limits of this function?

Tags: calculus, limits

Compute: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{ 1-x}}{x}$

Comment: sqrt x+1 means $\sqrt{x} + 1$ or $\sqrt{x+1}$? What about sqrt 1 - x? I'm guessing $\sqrt{1-x}$

Comment: $(\sqrt3-i)/2$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Comment: L'Hopital is not a good way of learning what the limits are but a really good way to check your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem was to compute the limit when x --> 2...

Comment: You don't need L'Hopital's rule here, the function is continuous at 2, so you can just substitute $x=2$ and evaluate, as @Berci has done.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are interested in $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x}}x$$
Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}$ to get
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x}}x \times \dfrac{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}} = \dfrac{(1+x)-(1-x)}{x(\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x})} = \dfrac{2x}{x(\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x})}\\ = \dfrac2{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x}}$$
Now can you finish it off?

Answer (score 0):

Just evaluate the function at $x = 2$.